# map of string and functions using boost gives compilation error

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to implement map of string and functions
I have put snippet of my program.

I have following implementation

```
void foo1(const std::string)
void foo2(const std::string)
void foo3(const std::string)

typedef boost::function<void, const std::string> fun_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, fun_t> funs_t;
funs_t f;

f["xyz"] = &foo1;
f["abc"] = &foo2;
f["pqr"] = &foo3;

std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;

for(std::string s: {"xyz", "abc", "pqr"}){

 tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, f.find(f_kb)->second, s));

}

for(auto& task : tasks){
    task.get();
}
```

it gives me error on line

```
f["xyz"] = &foo1;
```

that required from here

```
usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp225:18: error: no match for call to '(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Class sample, std::basic_string<char>>)(const std::basic_string<char> &)'

BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
```

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with code?

Comment: Seems like some semicolons are missing in there.

Comment: "that no match for call to" to what? Did you forget to copy/paste the error message?

Comment: Hi.. I have edited question sorry for being vague

Comment: Why don't you use `std::function`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl  It gives similar error no matching function for call to

Comment: Hmm... I doubt this is your real code. Other than the missing semicolons after the function declarations, the correct syntax would also be `std::function<void(const std::string)>`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, Boost.Function supports either syntax. It was first written when not all compilers supported function types as template arguments, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp209394560 (However, it's possible the `const` is causing the problem, since the actual function type is `void(std::string)` not `void(const std::string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comment on `function<>` is the correct one.

Here's your sample fixed up to work:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9176576f607d81d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

void foo1(std::string const& s) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << s << ")\n"; }
void foo2(std::string const& s) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << s << ")\n"; }
void foo3(std::string const& s) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << s << ")\n"; }

typedef boost::function<void(std::string const&)> fun_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, fun_t> funs_t;

int main() {
    funs_t f;

    f["xyz"] = &foo1;
    f["abc"] = &foo2;
    f["pqr"] = &foo3;

    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;

    for(std::string s: {"xyz", "abc", "pqr"}){

        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, f.find(s)->second, s));

    }

    for(auto& task : tasks){
        task.get();
    }
}
```

Prints something like:

```
void foo3(const string&)(pqr)
void foo2(const string&)(abc)
void foo1(const string&)(xyz)
```

(output varies depending on thread scheduling, which is implementation defined and non-deterministic)

Comment: I didn't know that Coliru supported Boost. Cool! :)